# How to call a function when the user clicks on the radio group options, even when the selected option doesn't change?

Tags: reactjs, antd, onchange, radio-group

I have used the antd `Radio Group` and I want to call a function when the user clicks on the options, no matter the option is selected or not.

I used the `onChange` but it works only in changing selected option cases.
Suppose I have this options in my radio group: A,B,C. Now A is selected. I want to `console.log("A")` when the user clicks on A. if the user clicks on A twice, I want to console.log twice.

```
import { Radio } from 'antd';
const RadioButton = Radio.Button;
const RadioGroup = Radio.Group;

function onChange(e) {
  console.log(`radio checked:${e.target.value}`);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <div>
      <RadioGroup onChange={onChange} defaultValue="a">
        <RadioButton value="a">Hangzhou</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton value="b">Shanghai</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton value="c">Beijing</RadioButton>
      </RadioGroup>
    </div>
  </div>
, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `onClick`, but it's unavailable to `RadioGroup` component. Hence, put it into each of the `Radio.Button` components would be a choice.

```
function onClick(e) {
  console.log(`radio clicked:${e.target.value}`);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <div>
      <RadioGroup onChange={onChange} defaultValue="a">
        <RadioButton onClick={onClick} value="a">Hangzhou</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton onClick={onClick} value="b">Shanghai</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton onClick={onClick} value="c">Beijing</RadioButton>
      </RadioGroup>
    </div>
  </div>
, mountNode);
```